# SwiftUI: Why the background exceeds the frame?

Tags: swiftui

Let's have a look at this simple code:

```swift
GeometryReader { gr in
    Text("hi there!")
        .frame(width: 2 * gr.size.width / 3, height: gr.size.height)
        .background(.yellow)
        .border(.gray)
}
```

Why the background exceeds the frame? The border however works as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the background function ignores the "safe area" (which is good in many cases). To prevent this from happening, simply write:

```swift
.background(.gray, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [])
```

More info at:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)

Comment: This thing is new, at past was good for having a limitation. Now apple mixed 2 modifier together, which I don’t think it was good move. As you can see one big problem of coder also me, was asking what is wrong with background?! Is the API broken. Or even this question! Apple just broke the api for no reason!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Color has changed to ignoring safe area/frame constraints and flows outside. The fix is to use a colored shape:

```
        GeometryReader { gr in
            Text("hi there!")
                .frame(width: 2 * gr.size.width / 3, height: gr.size.height)
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.yellow)
                )
                .border(.gray)
        }
```